# How to position a div in the middle of the screen when the page is bigger than the screen

Tags: css, html, window, center

Hi I'm using something similiar to the following to get a div positioned in the middle of the screen:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

</style>


<div id="mydiv">Test Div</div>
```

However the problem with this is it positions the item in the middle of the page not the screen. So if the page is a few screen high and I'm at the top of the page (the top part of the part is displayed on the screen) when I make the div appear it's not even on the screen. You have to scroll down to view it.

Can someone please tell me how you'd make it appear in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I just tested that exact code on a test page and it centered the div perfectly on the page, even with about 100 **`<br />`** before it to try and push it down. Maybe try checking the rest of your code to see if you have something that is either over-writing the DIV's values or that is effecting your DIV to cause these issues.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

just add `position:fixed` and it will keep it in view even if you scroll down. see it at http://jsfiddle.net/XEUbc/1/

```
#mydiv {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: You  are life saver.. Simple solution works well even if the element has transform scale applied..

Answer (score 103):

I think this is a simple solution:

```html
<div style="
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;">Full Center ON Page
</div>
```

Comment: this approach is far more better than approved answer

Comment: loved this one, but does this work in "older" browser?

Comment: Worked for me, optimized code... more awesome than accepted answer.

Answer (score 22):

Use transform;

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mydiv {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
</style>
```

Javascript Solution :

```
var left = (screen.width / 2) - (530 / 2);
var top = (screen.height / 2) - (500 / 2);
var _url = 'PopupListRepair.aspx';
window.open(_url, self, "width=530px,height=500px,status=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + ",scrollbars=no");
```

Answer (score 17):

Try this one.

```
.centered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: I think this one is more useful 'cuz you don't need to apply any style to the parent element.

Answer (score 6):

Just put `margin:auto;`

```
#mydiv {
    margin:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:30em;
    height:18em;
    margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```
<div id="mydiv">Test Div</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
```

This worked for me

Comment: While this may technically be correct, you want to include a brief description  of why this solves the problem for context

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Just add `position:fixed` and that will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Two ways to position a tag in the middle of screen or its parent tag:

#### Using positions:

Set the parent tag `position` to `relative` (if the target tag has a parent tag) and then set the target tag style like this:

```
#center {
  ...  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

#### Using flex:

The parent tag style should looks like this:

```
#parent-tag {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

#mydiv {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">Maitrey</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question was asked me in the interview "how you align the div center of the screen? "

Answer (score 1):

Well, below is the working example for this.

This will handle the center position if you resize the webpage or load in anysize.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border: 10px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid #3498db;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="loader" style="display:block"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In above sample ***loading div*** will always be in center.

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Answer (score 1):

```
#div {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position:fixed;
}
```

just set the above three properties any of your element and there you Go!

Your div is exactly at the center of the screen

Answer (score 0):

In ur script page...

```
    $('.a-middle').css('margin-top', function () {
        return ($(window).height() - $(this).height()) / 2
    });
```

Use a-middle class in the Div...

```
   <div class="a-middle">
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: -50px;
  border: 10px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid #3498db;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="loader" style="display:block"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**USING FLEX**

```
display: flex;
height: 100%;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: This centers content to the parent element or page, not the screen.

Answer (score -2):

```
width:30em;
position: static;
margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Answer (score -4):

For this you would have to detect screen size. That is not possible with CSS or HTML; you need JavaScript. Here is the Mozilla Developer Center entry on window properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window#Properties

Detect the available height and position accordingly.