# Trying to center a HTML table with suggestions from another thread

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

I'm creating a table in html. Wanted the table to come out at the center of the screen, and found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455362/how-to-center-a-table-of-the-screen-vertically-and-horizontally) showing me exactly how to center the table in HTML.

However, as much as it did help make my table appear at the center of the screen, it also added an additional row, atop the first row when I added these lines to my code:

```
<table border="1px" align="center">
<td align=center valign=center>
```

Here's a preview of my current table (with slight distortions):

```
<head>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border="1px" align="center">
        <td align=center valign=center>
            <col style="width: 200px" />
            <col style="width: 300px" span="2" />
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Degree</th>
                <td colspan="2">Bachelor of Multimedia</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">University</th>
                <td colspan="2">Universiti Utara Malaysia</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2">Contact</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td>019-xxxxxxx</td>
                <td>blah@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second line of code you added you jsut need

```
<table border="1px" align="center">
```

Remove

```
<td align=center valign=center>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CJ5N2/1/)**

Comment: Yup, wOrked! Thanks a TONS! :D

Answer (score 1):

The best way to have a table centered in a page is using the `margin:0 auto` in your CSS. If you want to use it inline(not a recommendation), use it this way: `style="margin:0 auto"`.
Try to use CSS property instead of `border`, `align` or `valign`.

But your real proble come from this line `td align=center valign=center>`. A `td` is a column that need to be in a `tr`(a row). But in fact, yo do not even need this line.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the 2nd line of your code:

```
<td align=center valign=center>
```

and it should work, here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNGck/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, mate! Every help counted!