# CSS: Centering elements vertically

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to develop my first responsive website but I'm having some trouble (of course).

I need an element (sort of a menu) to contain 4 row of elements and each element has an image to the left and some text to the right. Now, the issue I'm having is that I can't seem to be able to make the elements center vertically correctly. I've tried several methods that seem to work for a lot of people so I thought I'ld ask if anybody knows why nothing seems to work for me. 
This is what the image CSS looks like:

```
.tablaBuscadorElementos > img {
position: relative;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mampy3000/9JZdZ/1/

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Which elements are you trying to center vertically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your elements are inline-block , you can inject an inline-block pseudo-element 100% `height` and `vertical-align:middle` it to `img` and `span` : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9JZdZ/4/)**

basicly (+ below update of your CSS):

```
.tablaBuscadorElementos:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

---

```
.tablaBuscadorElementos {
    height:22%;/* instead min-height so value can be used for pseudo or direct child */ 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}
.tablaBuscadorElementos > span {
    font-size:20px;
    width:80%;
    vertical-align:middle; /* align to next inline-block element or baseline*/
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;/* layout*/
}
.tablaBuscadorElementos > img {
    vertical-align:middle; /* align to next inline-block element or baseline*/
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;

}

.tablaBuscador, .tablaBuscadorElementos{
    display:block;
}
.tablaBuscadorElementos:before {
    content:'';
    height:100%;/* calculated from 22% parent's height */
    display:inline-block;/* layout*/
    vertical-align:middle;/* align to next inline-block element or baseline*/
}
```

Comment: pseudo element can be :after, before could be used to insert your img/icon.

Comment: Great answer. After looking at it a bit I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Follow up question, I'm having some trouble replicating what you did. I'm not sure I get your method. Here is a similar Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mampy3000/zK4hS/

I want to replicate the vertical alignment in the grey div in the top (the one with a button and some text). Can you help me understand what I did wrong there? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this css  to .tablaBuscador

```
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
margin-top:-100px;  /* half of height */
```

More info here: [How to center a table of the screen (vertically and horizontally)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455362/how-to-center-a-table-of-the-screen-vertically-and-horizontally)

The newer option would be to use calc() but you might run into browser support issues.

```
position: fixed;
top:calc(50% - 100px).
```

Here are which browsers support calc(): http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a major tune-up.  You are floating elements, using vertical-align on them, positioning them relatively with left, right, top, and bottom set to 0.  None of these make any sense.  Here's a cleaned up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jL2Gz/.

And here's a tuned up code:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    height:100%;
}

.tablaBuscador {
    font-family: "Maven Pro", sans-serif;
    height:200px;
    width:40%;
}

.tablaBuscador > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.tablaBuscador > div > span {
    font-size:20px;
    width:80%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.tablaBuscador > div > img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.tablaBuscador > div > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```