# How render form at the center

Tags: jsf

I have facelet `1.xhtml` with the following

```
<h:form id="frm">
    ...
</h:form>
```

How render this form at the center of screen entirely?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a `div` and using some CSS?

Comment: @peeskillet No, i dont about CSS nothink. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStyleSheet library="css" name="stylesheet.css/>
</h:head>   

<div id="formdiv">    
    <h:form id="frm">
        ...
    </h:form>
<div>
```

**stylesheet.css**

```
#formdiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

-Or-

```
<head>
    <style>
        #formdiv {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<h:body>
    <div id="formdiv">    
        <h:form id="frm">
            ...
        </h:form>
    <div>
</h:body>
```

Also see [How to center a div horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div-horizontally)

And [How to position div in middle of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012111/how-to-position-a-div-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-when-the-page-is-bigger-than-t)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the content of your form you may need to apply the CSS style at a deeper level than an outermost div

```
 <div class="centred-form">
    <h:form>
       <h:panelGrid>
          ...
       </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

will centre the form but the panel grid will be left aligned on the form defeating the purpose.

Instead you can apply a style class to the panel grid:

```
    <h:form>
       <h:panelGrid styleClass="centred-form">
          ...
       </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and the CSS

```
.centred-form {
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```