# Location div in the middle

Tags: html, css

This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/twy161er/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="top">
Logo. Menu
</div>

<div id="content">
Text Text Text
</div>

<div id="bottom">
Text in the bottom
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#content {
}
```

I want the "content" div to be in the center and in the middle of the page.

How should I do it?

Comment: Quick and simple: Centering with flexbox - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a parent div `.main` for the three `DIV` and add a wrap `DIV` tag for content text and use display `table`  `table-row` `table-cell`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.main {
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.top {
 height: 0;                /* make it dynamic */
 background-color: red;
 display: table-row;
}
.bottom {
 height: 0;                /* make it dynamic */
 background-color: lime;
 display: table-row;
}
.content {
 display: table-row;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background: yellow;
}
.content div {
    text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="top">
    Logo. Menu<br />
    Dynamic content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Text Text Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Text in the bottom<br />
    Dynamic content
  </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle demo : https://jsfiddle.net/twy161er/15/

Why use `display:table`? Because the `content text` always show even if the window height less than 200px; and you get IE8/9 support.

Comment: Yes, that is wrong.. It should be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: @Cattla May I make a few modifications to your code? .. Mainly to remove absolute positioning, which is not needed and should be avoided.

Comment: @Cattla Done, now you need to update your fiddle yourself :)

Comment: Your're welcome, your were too close for me to add an answer of my own using `display: table` (which is my favorite for older browser support when a flex-like solution is wanted)

Comment: @Cattla Thanks! It support IE8/9 too?

Comment: @Roy yes, support > IE8 :)

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty simple!

You can make the contents of the `#content` like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>Text Text Text</div>
</div>
```

Then, all you need to do is add this CSS:

```
#content {}

#content div {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Explanation**

You firstly `absolute` your text. Then, you reset the `margin` and `padding` of the element `<div>`. What you do then is, push the inner `<div>` down by `50%` of the page height and push left by `50%` of the page width. Then, you have to move it towards the left, `50%` of its width, and move it towards the top, `50%` of it's height. That way, you can get the exact center of the `<div>`.

Working example: [JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/twy161er/12/)

Comment: This solution overlaps header when content gets bigger ... https://jsfiddle.net/twy161er/14/

Comment: @LGSon Don't you think the only thing the OP wants is to vertically and horizontally center the line of text..?

Comment: I think that a solution that overlaps like this is less good no matter what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

CSS rule "margin: auto" to the #content div should put it on the middle horizontally.

In order to put it in the middle of the screen, try:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

taken from here [How to position a div in the middle of the screen when the page is bigger than the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012111/how-to-position-a-div-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-when-the-page-is-bigger-than-t)

Notice that your top and bottom divs are in absolute position, so no way to tell the #content div to position itself relatively to them.

Comment: Well what if the page is scrolled... it will move down.

Comment: Position fixed is not a good solution, and is not the solution he is looking for.

Comment: This is depending of what he try to accomplish. if he want the conent to align center but not fix in the middle of screen, then he can use "absolute" instead of "fixed"

Comment: yes, this is the answer of @HassanAlthaf, may be better with a **div** instead  of **p**.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf will have some problem on scroll, position absolute need a body height of 100% to be crossbrowser, but than you'll have again a problem while scrolling.

Answer (score -3):

Your content is missing reference to id "#".

And i hope this is solution to your problem.

```
#content {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the content text is in the center, but not in the middle. I want it to be in the middle... I meant that the space between the top to the content divs will be the same as the space between the content to the bottom divs.

Comment: its not just matter of missing #