# Is there any way to center emement on screen (not document)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have got a question. Is it possible to center an element relative to the screen not to the document.
(The document is smaller than the screen)
So my actual problem is to detect if the offset is above or under the document.
This returns the offset:

```
var $offset = screen.height - document.height
```

But I cant detect if it is at the top of the screen or at the bottom :(

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a div in the middle of the screen when the page is bigger than the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012111/how-to-position-a-div-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-when-the-page-is-bigger-than-t)

Comment: "_relative to the screen_", no, this is not possible. You can position an element relative to it's view window only. Though you can calculate the position of the view window related to the screen, and then reposition the element. I'm not sure, if there's an event for detecting if window is moving.

Comment: @Tony no my problem is if the document its smaller than the screen

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. I don't understand what is inside what.

Comment: Checkout this link:http://jsfiddle.net/kdzD9/164/. Please let me know if this is not what you want.

Comment: There's not information enough in your question to answer it properly, but maybe something [like this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/959uc9LL/1/)? The fiddle works with FireFox only, but there are `mozInnerScreenY` corresponds in other browsers. If you need the positioning only once, just remove the interval, and run the function only.