# How to position inputs lower on the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 inputs, a username and a password. I've aligned them in the middle, but I can't figure out how to push them lower down the screen and stay in the middle. Can anyone send me a reference to do so?

Comment: Can you please post your code and update with what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a div in the middle of the screen when the page is bigger than the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012111/how-to-position-a-div-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-when-the-page-is-bigger-than-t)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to do without the relevant code, but here's a solution that might work for you:

```css
form {
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="name" />
<input type="password" placeholder="password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds something you can use Flexbox for. Make the containing div a flexbox and then justify and align to the center.